# htdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, composer-php, google-signin

i have host a website on infinityfree, evrything is working except the google auth2. Composer is installed, ran "require oauth2-client-bundle league/oauth2-google". I also did dump-autoload many times. but when i upload vendor, composer.json, and composer.lock on hosting server, it first give me an error like this,

"Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.8"

then i change the version from 80000 to 70000 in platform_check.php file. after that i recieve this error

"Warning: require(/home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_29855175/htdocs/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_29855175/htdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71"

"Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_29855175/htdocs/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in /home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_29855175/htdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71"

and this is the code i used for google oauth2

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include('config.php');

    //google login script
    if(isset($_GET["code"])){
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);

        if(!isset($token['error'])){
            $client->setAccessToken($token["access_token"]);
            $_SESSION["access_token"] = $token["access_token"];

            $google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
            $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['given_name'];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $data['family_name'];
            $_SESSION['user_img'] = $data['picture'];
            $_SESSION['login_button'] = false;
            
        }
    }
?>
```

this is the config.php file that i included in above code line 2

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';


$cilentId = "622147488148-tub019fppvs05mt6mqfn3vauk8omhhfj.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$clientSecret = "z8L-i8KOC4Qmry97OB6xQIFY";
$redirect = "http://localhost/test/login.php";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($cilentId);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");
$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();

?>
```

this is composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "2.10",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.3",
        "league/oauth2-google": "^4.0"
    }
}
```

I got no clue where to start this troubleshooting, any help please...

Comment: Please don't manually edit files in the `vendor` folder. Better resolve this problem properly - what does your `composer.json` specify? Did you use a different PHP version in your development environment?

Comment: i forgot to write the composer.json file configuration file i have included in the post, please take a look in it

Comment: Did you use a different PHP version in your development environment? Like: you've used PHP 8 in your development environment, installed any package that is not compatible with PHP 7, and deployed this?

Comment: I used php 8.0.8 for both development environment and packages.

Comment: As given in the error message: your production server is not using that PHP version. Either upgrade your server, downgrade the PHP version in your local environment (both ways should result in both environments using the same version), or use the `platform` configuration to ensure that no incompatible packages are installed